# MPI C++ class object use member function on slave processors

Tags: c++, class, mpi

I am writing a code to send fixed number of rows (split along first dimension in case of 2D) and a slab (for 3D, again split along the first dimension). For example for a 100x100 I would like to send 25x100 to each of the 4 processors and in case of 3D (100x100x100) I would like to send 25x100x100 to each processors.

I have a class file and I create instance of class in the main program. My question is how 1) How can I create class objects for each process (mpi rank) and be able to use the member functions (example my_average) in the code. 2) If I create instance of class inside enclosing parenthesis the I get scope issues. 3) In the output attached below I see that send is not working. What am I missing? Is this the right way to do things.

Please help.

Pardon my lingo - c++ is not my first language.

Attached sample output.

```
 each process gets 2
 First Dimension 4
 Number of processors 2
 Displacement  and blocklen  0    8
 Displacement  and blocklen  8    8
 Displacement  and blocklen  0    8
 Displacement  and blocklen  8    8
(  0.0000 + i -0.0000)(  1.0000 + i -1.1315)(  2.0000 + i -2.7556)(  3.0000 + i -3.4587) 
(  0.5328 + i  0.4672)(  1.2190 + i -0.2190)(  2.0470 + i -1.0470)(  3.6789 + i -2.6789) 
(  1.3586 + i  1.3207)(  2.8694 + i  0.0653)(  2.7670 + i -0.3835)(  4.0388 + i -1.5194) 
(  2.4929 + i  2.1690)(  1.1037 + i  1.9654)(  2.1604 + i  0.9465)(  4.5891 + i -0.5297) 

 end of 2D  matrix 

  rank=0 Rows : 2 Width : 4 local_n0 size 2
(  0.0000 + i -0.0000)(  1.0000 + i -1.1315)(  2.0000 + i -2.7556)(  3.0000 + i -3.4587)
(  0.5328 + i  0.4672)(  1.2190 + i -0.2190)(  2.0470 + i -1.0470)(  3.6789 + i -2.6789)
rank=1 Rows : 2 Width : 4 local_n0 size 2
(  0.0000 + i  0.0000)(  0.0000 + i  0.0000)(  0.0000 + i  0.0000)(  0.0000 + i  0.0000)
(  0.0000 + i  0.0000)(  0.0000 + i  0.0000)(  0.0000 + i  0.0000)(  0.0000 + i  0.0000)
```

main program

```
#include <fftw3-mpi.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> // needed for setfill
#include "cmplx_2d.hh"
#include "random.hh"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  const int N0 = 4, N1 = 4;

  int i,j;

  int rank,size;
  double rx;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    int local_n0=N0/size;

   if(rank==0){
   cout << " each process gets " << local_n0 << endl;
   cout << " First Dimension " << N0 << endl;
   cout << " Number of processors " << size << endl;
   }

/* compute start and size of rows */
   int n_rows[size];
   int send_counts[size];
   int displs[size];
   displs[0]=0;
   for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        n_rows[i]=N0/size;
        if(i<N0%size){
                n_rows[i]=n_rows[i]+1;
        }
        send_counts[i]=n_rows[i]*N1;
        if(i>0){
                displs[i]=displs[i-1]+send_counts[i-1];
        }
        cout << " Displacement  and blocklen  " << displs[i] << "    " << send_counts[i] << endl;
   }

   int rows=n_rows[rank];

/* create 2d complex objects */
   cmplx_2d arr_cmplx(N0,N1);

   if(rank==0) {
/* initialize data -- random number */
     for (i = 0; i < N0; ++i) {
           for (j = 0; j < N1; ++j){
              rx =((double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX);
              arr_cmplx(i,j)=complex<double>(rx*i+j,i-j-rx);
              printf("(%8.4f + i%8.4f)", real(arr_cmplx(i,j)), imag(arr_cmplx(i,j)));
           }
           printf(" \n  ");
     }
         printf(" \n end of 2D  matrix \n \n  ");
   } // end of master 

     if(rank==0) {
        MPI_Scatterv(&arr_cmplx(0,0),send_counts,displs,MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX,MPI_IN_PLACE,0,MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
     } else {
          /* I should allocate local array on each processor to receive data but if I do it here I get scope error */
         //cmplx_2d arr_cmplx(rows,N1);
         MPI_Scatterv(NULL,send_counts,displs,MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX,&arr_cmplx(0,0),rows*N1,MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
     }

   //printing, one proc at a time
   if(rank>0){
      MPI_Status status;
      MPI_Recv(NULL,0,MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX,rank-1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
    }
    cout<<"rank="<< rank<<" Rows : "<<rows<<" Width : "<<N1<< " local_n0 size " << local_n0 << endl;

    for(i=0; i<rows; i++) 
    {
            for(j=0; j<N1; j++)
                printf("(%8.4f + i%8.4f)", real(arr_cmplx(i,j)), imag(arr_cmplx(i,j)));
                cout<<endl;
    }

    if(rank<size-1){
      MPI_Send(NULL,0,MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX,rank+1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

   MPI_Finalize();
   return 0;
}
```

header file

```
#include <cassert> // for assert()
#include <complex> 

using namespace std;

class cmplx_2d
{
private:
        int nx;
        int ny;
        complex<double>** array_2d;
public:
// constructor
cmplx_2d(int x, int y) {
  array_2d = new complex<double>*[x];
   for(int i(0); i < x; ++i) {
      array_2d[i] = new complex<double>[y];
     for(int j(0); j < y; ++j) {
         array_2d[i][j]= complex<double>(0.,0.);
     }}
     nx=x;
     ny=y;
}
// deconstructor
~cmplx_2d() {
  delete [] array_2d;
}
// overload () operator       
 complex<double>& operator()(const int i, const int j) const;

// prototype of overload constructor - just a dummy function
void my_avg( const cmplx_2d& in, int* ir, int* il, int* jr, int* jl, const int flag  );

int getNx() const {
        return nx;
}
int getNy() const {
        return ny;
}

};  // end of class
```

header file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cmplx_2d.hh"
#include "main_header.hh"

// overload constructor to - just a dummy for now
void cmplx_2d::my_avg( const cmplx_2d& in, int* ir, int* il, int* jr, int* jl,  const int flag  ) {
      nx=in.getNx();
      ny=in.getNy();

if ( flag == DX )
{
// derivative with respect to x
     for(int i(0); i < nx; ++i) {
       for(int j(0); j < ny; ++j) {
                array_2d[i][j] = 0.5*(in(ir[i],j)+in(il[i],j));
     }} 
}
else
{
      std::cout << "NOT a  valid flag for derivative!" << std::endl;
}

} // end

// overloading of () parenthesis operator                                       
complex<double>& cmplx_2d::operator()(const int i, const int j) const
{
     assert(i >= 0 && i < nx);
     assert(j >= 0 && j < ny);
     return array_2d[i][j];
}
```

main header

```
const double PI=4.0*atan(1.0);
const double TWO_PI=2.0*PI;
enum flag {DX, DY, LAP};
```